# Union of the Intersection of Infinite Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, I'm trying to make sense of this question:

"Suppose we have an $A_n$ for each n $\in$ **N** (i.e. **N** is the Naturals. Each $A_n$ is an arbitrary set). Fill in the blanks with four words to get a true statement. Justify your answer.

x $\in$ $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}$ $A_n$ iff x $\in$ $A_n$ for [**blank**] [**blank**] [**blank**] [**blank**] n $\in$ **N**"

So far, I understand that for a given k, if x $\in$ ($\bigcap_{n=k}^{infinity}$ $A_n$ = $A_k$ $\cap$ $A_{k+1}$ $\cap$ $A_{k+2}$ $\cap$ ....) $\implies$ x $\in$ $A_n$ for all n$ 
\geqslant$ k

But I'm stuck on interpreting the next stage. If x $\in$ $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}$ $A_n$, then x $\in$ ({$A_1$ $\cap$ $A_{2}$ $\cap$ $A_{3}$ $\cap$...} $\bigcup$ {$A_2$ $\cap$ $A_{3}$ $\cap$ $A_{4}$ $\cap$...} $\bigcup$....). Which just means that $\exists$ some b $\in$ **N** s.t. x $\in$ **$A_n$** for all $n\geqslant$ b.

Have I interpreted this all correctly, and if so how could I translate what I've got so far into the 4 words? If I've misinterpreted the situation, have you any thoughts as to what I'm lacking?

Many thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: You could fill in the blanks with some phrase like "for all sufficiently large" or "for all but finitely many".

Comment: Some authors use the succinct term "eventually", as in $x \in A_n$ eventually.

Comment: People who write math books like this deserve to be shot.  I have no idea what four words the author wants, but you described it perfectly:  $x$ is in all $A_n$ for all $n$ greater than some $k$. "for all but finitely many n" is a very nice way of putting it but it's unreasonable to have guess the words exactly.  I, personally, had a hard time figuring out how to put $n\in N$ at the *end* rather than the middle of the phrase.  Which is stupid because IT DOES NOT MATTER.

Comment: A student could claim "conditions I don't know" form a true stateement.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, really appreciate it! I think you guys have cleared it up with the suggestions of what to write, and I'm really glad to hear I understood it all. And fleablood, I couldn't agree with you more! So, so much of the texts in maths and science are written in a way that reads efficiently and pretty for the author, who is incredibly experienced in the topic, but almost indecipherable for the student. The system is absolutely backwards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"all except finitely many" is what I would write there. That is the definition of [\liminf ]. By the way, remember the command for "infinite" is \infty.

Comment: Ah thank you, I really appreciate it! Apologies for the incorrect Mathjax, it's only my second time using it. Thanks again.